# ListViewThreshold - Filtering a view

Tags: list-view-threshold

I have a SharePoint List that is over the 5000 List View Threshhold.

I have a filtered View of this list that has only 150 items. I have used Indexed Columns and ensured the **first** filter in my view returns less than 5000 items.

The view displays correctly in the page/web part.

However, when we use the column header (with little triangle) to filter the list by a column (an Indexed one) we get the error that we are over the listview threshold and are not able to filter.

Any solutions?

Comment: I think you still might be able to use a text filter or HTML form filter by passing filter values or parameters to the list web part.

Comment: Facing same issue, did you get the solution to this?